# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot use dedicated Nvidia GPU / cannot disable integrated GPU / PRIME does not seem to work

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, gpu

My problem is stated in the title. I have installed Nvidia 440 driver successfully yet games use integrated Intel 530 GPU. Details section in settings also show Intel GPU regardless of what i do.`lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA` command also shows Intel 530. Don't really know what to do.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 530
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

~~

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: i did as you told

Comment: So you see that Nvidia driver is installed. All looks OK. You can switch to Nvidia by running `sudo prime-select nvidia` and reboot.

Comment: it says "Info: the nvidia profile is already set" and changes nothing when i reboot.

Comment: OK. Post the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` to your question.

Comment: That's a problem. I have no solution now. More info is needed.

Comment: added the output

Comment: I saw it, something is wrong with PRIME indeed. What is the kernel version?

Comment: 5.3.0-26-generic if im nor wrong

Comment: That must be the problem. Is it a fresh install? The 5.3 kernel has many problems with Nvidia drivers. Or did you update from the 5.0 kernel? If that is the case, boot with the 5.0 kernel.

Comment: yeah i have installed 2 days ago. i will try to boot with 5.0 kernel now

Comment: Tried rolling back to kernel 5.0 yet prime doesn't seem to make anything happen

Comment: I give up then.

Comment: It may be a long shot, but I had the same problem and solved it by removing the nouveau driver (`sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`). Maybe worth the try.

Comment: tried that but its still the same